# I cannot add new publication for snapshot replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

i'm gonna create a snapshot replication on sql server 2008 R2 database instance, but when on Replication Node, on Local publications , i'm using new publication sub menu, i get this error Message :

### New Publication Wizard

SQL Server is unable to connect to server '192.168.1.7'.

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1600.1&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.PubWizardErrorSR&EvtID=CantConnect&LinkId=20476

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server. Connections through a server alias, IP address, or any other alternate name are not supported. Specify the actual server name, 'SHAHEDINSTDB02'. (Replication.Utilities)

when i use computer name for connecting to sql server, after connecting, i get this error message again,
could you please he;p me?

Answer (score 0):

You may have an instance name too like SharedDBServer\DB02. You will have to use that full name. If SQL browser isn't running, create a sql alias to define the port it will need to connect with.